# Number of cycles of doubling map mod n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, irreducible-polynomials

Playing with some rhythm ideas, I stumbled on the sequence [A000374](https://oeis.org/A000374). It claims that the number of cycles of $f(x) = 2x \bmod n$ is the same as the number of distinct irreducible factors of $x^n - 1 \bmod 2$ (and furthermore that the degrees of the factors correspond to the lengths of the cycles), but no proof is given, and I can't see how the linked paper relates. This is a fascinating result to me. How does it work?

Comment: What is defined as the number of cycle of a function ?

Comment: @EDX, if $n$ is odd, then the function in this question is a permutation on the integers modulo $n$, and we're counting cycles in the usual sense when discussing permutations.

Comment: Let's just look at an example, $n=31$. The cycles are $(0),(1\ 2\ 4\ 8\ 16),(3\ 6\ 12\ 24\ 17),(5\ 10\ 20\ 9\ 18),(7\ 14\ 28\ 25\ 19),(11\ 22\ 13\ 26\ 21),(15\ 30\ 29\ 27\ 23)$.

Comment: The factorization is $(x + 1) (x^5 + x^2 + 1) (x^5 + x^3 + 1) (x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) (x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1) (x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1) (x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1)$

Comment: rhythm ideas? Care to explain that a bit, how this would be related to rhythms?

Comment: @Snared, construct a repeating sequence of notes such that if you accent every other note, you get the same melody back again (at half speed). This sequence is the number of distinct pitches you are able to use, for a given length.

Answer (score 2):

This is far from being a complete answer but may be useful in illustrating the relationship. For an immediate simplification, suppose $n$ to be an odd prime.

Let $Q$ be the order of $2$ modulo $n$. Then the cycles of $f$ are $(0)$ and $\frac{n-1}{Q}$ cycles of length $Q$, one of which is $(1,2,4, ...,2^{Q-1}).$

The irreducible factors are less easy to deal with. However, consider an irreducible factor of $x^n-1$ mod $2$. Over a splitting field let its roots be $\{w^t\}$ where $t\in S=\{a,b,c,...\}$.

Then we know that, for example, $w^a+w^b+w^c+...$ is either $0$ or $1$. Then squaring  gives the same value for  $(w^a+w^b+w^c+...)^2=(w^2)^a+(w^2)^b+(w^2)^c+...$. Similarly we can look at $(w^aw^b+w^aw^c+...)^2$ and so on.

We can conclude that our irreducible factor also has roots $\{w^{2t}\}$ where $t\in S$. In other words multiplying by $2$ simply permutes the elements of $S$.

$S$ therefore consists of cycles of $f$. Of course, it remains to prove that  $S$ is **precisely** one cycle.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting the gist, though visualizing these abstract splitting fields is a bit difficult for my computational brain.  Thank you for this answer, it was definitely helpful and I need to keep pondering it.